# Elixir: Is there a more concise way to run Tasks?

Tags: elixir

I've just started experimenting with Tasks in Elixir.

1) Is there a more concise way to start N [Tasks](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html)?

2) would I be better off creating a [Map](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html) of {symbol, task} vs. a [List](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/List.html) of Tasks?

```
stocks=["bsx","wmt"]

# assume this is a long-running function
longfunc = fn(sym) -> "nyse:"<>sym end 

tasks = Enum.reduce(stocks, [], fn(x,acc) -> [Task.async(fn -> longfunc.(x) end)| acc] end )

Enum.map(tasks, &Task.await/1)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`Task.async_stream/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#async_stream/5) provides a simple interface for running a list of tasks. Here's an example using `Task.async_stream/3`:

```rb
["bsx", "wmt"]
|> Task.async_stream(&("nyse:" <> &1))
|> Enum.to_list() # or any stream enumeration
#⇒ [ok: "nyse:bsx", ok: "nyse:wmt"]
```

Comment: I specifically want to call longfunc. with an argument - I'm having a tough time with that syntax.   Task.async_stream(&longfunc.(&1)/1)  is not correct.

Comment: If `longfunc` is anonymous, you can do `|> Task.async_stream(longfunc)`. If it's a named function, you can do `|> Task.async_stream(&longfunc/1)`.